# How do I make FFMPEG check yes while installing OPENCV

Tags: ffmpeg, cmake, opencv

I run

```
    cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE ..
```

to configure opencv

and here are some of the check result

```
--   Video I/O:
--     DC1394 1.x:                  NO
--     DC1394 2.x:                  NO
--     FFMPEG:                      NO
--       avcodec:                   YES (ver 57.64.101)
--       avformat:                  YES (ver 57.56.100)
--       avutil:                    YES (ver 55.34.100)
--       swscale:                   YES (ver 4.2.100)
--       avresample:                NO
--     GStreamer:                   NO
--     OpenNI:                      NO
--     OpenNI PrimeSensor Modules:  NO
--     OpenNI2:                     NO
```

to confirm I do have ffmpeg installed I run

```
ffmpeg
```

and the result shows

```
  ffmpeg version 3.2.2 Copyright (c) 2000-2016 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 4.8.2 (GCC)
  configuration: --enable-shared --enable-gpl --enable-libx264 --enable-      libxvid --enable-pic --enable-ffplay --extra-cflags='-I/usr/include/SDL:/usr    /local/include/SDL2' --extra-ldflags=-L/usr/local/lib64 --extra-libs=-lSDL
  libavutil      55. 34.100 / 55. 34.100
  libavcodec     57. 64.101 / 57. 64.101
  libavformat    57. 56.100 / 57. 56.100
  libavdevice    57.  1.100 / 57.  1.100
  libavfilter     6. 65.100 /  6. 65.100
  libswscale      4.  2.100 /  4.  2.100
  libswresample   2.  3.100 /  2.  3.100
  libpostproc    54.  1.100 / 54.  1.100
  Hyper fast Audio and Video encoder
  usage: ffmpeg [options] [[infile options] -i infile]... {[outfile options] outfile}...
```

So I do have ffmpeg installed,then why cmake won't recongnise it?What is missing?

Comment: It says FFmpeg developers so it has the header files installed here are some of the cmake file check result 
    package 'gstreamer-video-0.10' not found
    package 'gstreamer-app-0.10' not found
    package 'gstreamer-riff-0.10' not found
    package 'gstreamer-pbutils-0.10' not found
    package 'libdc1394-2' not found
    package 'libdc1394' not found
    Looking for linux/videodev.h - found
    Looking for sys/videoio.h - not found
    found libavcodec, version 57.64.101
    found libavutil, version 55.34.100
    found libswscale, version 4.2.100
 'libavresample' not found

Comment: I noticed sys/video.h is marked not found is that has something do to with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I happen to be reinstalling my OpenCV recently and here are the steps to configure ffmepg.

1.Download the yum repository here to ~/Desktop
https://download1.rpmfusion.org/free/el/rpmfusion-free-release-7.noarch.rpm

2.Install the repository

```
sudo rpm -i ~/Desktop/rpmfusion-free-release-7.noarch.rpm
```

3.Install FFMPEG

```
sudo yum -install ffmpeg.x86_64 ffmpeg-devel.x86_64 ffmpeg-libs.x86_64
```

4.Edit common.h file

```
sudo gedit /usr/include/ffmpeg/common.h
```

Insert the following code at line:28

```
#ifndef UINT64_C
#define UINT64_C(value) __CONCAT(value, ULL)
#endif
```

And It is done